# Have unexpected hostname and IP

Tags: debian, dns

I built a new rPi3 with Stretch on it; its name is rpi3ohv2.

I set it up as 192.168.1.4 and later (Dec 28) changed it to .5
When I ping, dig and nslookup it, it comes up as .4

```
nslookup rpi3ohv2.argylecourt.org
Server:         192.168.1.7
Address:        192.168.1.7#53

Name:   rPi3OHv2.argylecourt.org
Address: 192.168.1.4
```

I have a local DHCP server running on .7; neither its lease file (/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases) nor its config (/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf) does contain an entry for .4. However, the new machine rpi3ohv2 has a fixed/reserved entry:

```
host node5 {
        # RaspberryPi Automation v2 -> rPi3OHv2
        hardware ethernet B8:27:EB:71:48:B3;
        fixed-address 192.168.1.5;
}
```

Doing a local nslookup by IP on .5 says:

```
nslookup 192.168.1.5
Server:         192.168.1.7
Address:        192.168.1.7#53

5.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa        name = rpiautomation.argylecourt.org.
```

... which is the name of the old machine (which I replaced with the new one, called rpi3ohv2).

The longer I think about this, this seems to be a DNS problem, not DHCP.

The TTLs are defined as follows:

```
;$ORIGIN .
$TTL    86400      ; 1 day
;rpiserver.argylecourt.org. IN SOA rpiserver.argylecourt.org. hostmaster.argylecourt.org. (
@ IN SOA rpiserver.argylecourt.org. hostmaster.argylecourt.org. (
        2018020402 ; serial
                8H ; refresh
                4H ; retry
                4W ; expire
                1D ; minimum
)
argylecourt.org. IN NS rpiserver.argylecourt.org.
argylecourt.org. IN MX 10 rpiserver.argylecourt.org.

;$ORIGIN argylecourt.org.

rpiserver       IN      A       192.168.1.7
www             IN      CNAME   argylecourt.org
```

[update] I have since updated the serial number to 2019020201 and the expire value to 2W, and ran the following commands on .5:

```
# [2019-02-03 08:28] maxg@rpi3ohv2 ~ $
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
# [2019-02-03 08:29] maxg@rpi3ohv2 ~ $
nslookup rpi3ohv2
Server:         192.168.1.7
Address:        192.168.1.7#53

Name:   rPi3OHv2.argylecourt.org
Address: 192.168.1.4

# [2019-02-03 08:29] maxg@rpi3ohv2 ~ $
hostname
rpi3ohv2
# [2019-02-03 08:29] maxg@rpi3ohv2 ~ $
hostname -i
192.168.1.5
# [2019-02-03 08:29] maxg@rpi3ohv2 ~ $
hostname -I
192.168.1.5
# [2019-02-03 08:29] maxg@rpi3ohv2 ~ $
nslookup 192.168.1.5
Server:         192.168.1.7
Address:        192.168.1.7#53

5.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa        name = rpiautomation.argylecourt.org.
```

... same outcome; as in, .5 still resolves to rPiAutmation (old machine), and rPi3OHv2 (new machine) resolves to .4

```
# [2019-02-03 08:42] maxg@rpi3ohv2 ~ $
dig rpiautomation.argylecourt.org

; > DiG 9.10.3-P4-Raspbian > rpiautomation.argylecourt.org
;rpiautomation.argylecourt.org. IN      A

; AUTHORITY SECTION:
argylecourt.org.        86400   IN      SOA     rpiserver.argylecourt.org. hostmaster.argylecourt.org. 2017061536 28800 14400 604800 86400

; SERVER: 192.168.1.7#53(192.168.1.7)
; WHEN: Sun Feb 03 08:43:11 AEST 2019

# [2019-02-03 08:43] maxg@rpi3ohv2 ~ $
dig rpi3ohv2.argylecourt.org

; > DiG 9.10.3-P4-Raspbian > rpi3ohv2.argylecourt.org
;rpi3ohv2.argylecourt.org.      IN      A

; ANSWER SECTION:
rPi3OHv2.argylecourt.org. 3600  IN      A       192.168.1.4

; AUTHORITY SECTION:
argylecourt.org.        86400   IN      NS      rpiserver.argylecourt.org.

; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
rpiserver.argylecourt.org. 86400 IN     A       192.168.1.7
```

This is a DNS problem... is there a hidden cache file of sort?

I have now rebooted the "network services" machine .7 (hosting DNS and BIND9), and noticed that zone files with the old serial number have been loaded; yet they have been updated, and confirmed that with cat.

```
# [2019-02-03 08:58] maxg@rpiserver ~ $
sudo service bind9 status
● bind9.service - BIND Domain Name Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bind9.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-02-03 08:55:17 AEST; 6min ago
     Docs: man:named(8)
 Main PID: 494 (named)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bind9.service
           └─494 /usr/sbin/named -f -u bind

Feb 03 08:55:20 rpiserver named[494]: managed-keys-zone: journal file is out of date: removing journal file
Feb 03 08:55:20 rpiserver named[494]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 641
Feb 03 08:55:20 rpiserver named[494]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Feb 03 08:55:20 rpiserver named[494]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Feb 03 08:55:20 rpiserver named[494]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Feb 03 08:55:20 rpiserver named[494]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Feb 03 08:55:20 rpiserver named[494]: zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2017061507
Feb 03 08:55:20 rpiserver named[494]: zone argylecourt.org/IN: loaded serial 2017061536
Feb 03 08:55:20 rpiserver named[494]: all zones loaded
Feb 03 08:55:20 rpiserver named[494]: running
# [2019-02-03 09:01] maxg@rpiserver ~ $
cd /etc/bind/zones/
# [2019-02-03 09:02] maxg@rpiserver /etc/bind/zones $
la
total 16
drwxr-sr-x 2 root bind 4096 Feb  3 08:54 .
drwxr-sr-x 3 root bind 4096 Feb  3 07:07 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root bind 1202 Feb  3 08:28 argylecourt.org.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root bind  609 Feb  3 08:38 rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa
```

Where do I need to look to fix this problem?

Comment: So, you are using a DHCP server, but you want to set a specific IP address for your machine?

Comment: yes; it has a server function, and needs a fixed IP.

Comment: Does the server's DHCP server know your machine's MAC address and does it associate that with a particular IP address in its configuration (that's how the DHCP servers I know work)? If not, then it may just hand out any address in the free pool.

Comment: Is the MAC address in the DHCP server's configuration correct and has the DHCP server been restarted or forced to reload it configuration since the configuration was updated with your static address?  Also, how is the name server configured? Should it automatically be updated from the DHCP server somehow?

Comment: I have restarted both bind9 and dhcp. I have not made any config changes to the server providing these services on .7 other than editing /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf and changing the MAC address to the new machine.

Comment: And yes, DHCP and DNS share a secret key for DHCP updates which I configured in June 2017 (no changes to that config since).

Comment: Have you updated the serial for the DNS? Otherwise clients don't know you've changed anything. (At the moment it looks like a YYYYMMDDNN sequence, which would suggest you've not updated it since February a year ago.)

Comment: Yes, correct; just changed it to 2019020201... no change.

Comment: Looks a bit like this problem: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8851

Comment: Well, I am not sure... the problem now seem to be the zone files. And from what i gather, my serial is from 2017, was updated in 2018, and again today with 2019... but it loads only the 2017 serial; do not even understand where DNS gets this zone file from.

Answer (score 1):

I started digging further when I realised the old serial number. I looked up cat /etc/bind/named.conf.local, which pointed to [file "/var/lib/bind/argylecourt.org.db";] ... while I was updating /etc/bind/zones/argylecourt.org.db